# Why does String.subscript(_:) require the types `String.Index` and `Int` to be equal when there is no `Int` involved?

Tags: swift, xcode, foundation

I fail to understand the problem Xcode is confronting me with in this line:

```
iteration.template = template[iterationSubstring.endIndex...substring.startIndex]
```

`template` is a `String` and `iterationSubstring` and `substring` are `Substring`s of `template`. Xcode highlights the opening square bracket with the following message:

> Subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires the types 'Substring.Index' and 'Int' be equivalent

The error message does not make any sense to me. I try to obtain a `Substring` by creating a `Range<String.Index>` with the `[template.startIndex...template.endIndex]` subscript. How is this related to `Int`? And why does the same pattern work elsewhere?

---

Xcode playground code reproducing the problem:

```
import Foundation
let template = "This is an ordinary string literal."

let firstSubstringStart = template.index(template.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
let firstSubstringEnd = template.index(template.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
let firstSubstring = template[firstSubstringStart...firstSubstringEnd]

let secondSubstringStart = template.index(template.startIndex, offsetBy: 10)
let secondSubstringEnd = template.index(template.startIndex, offsetBy: 12)
let secondSubstring = template[secondSubstringStart...secondSubstringEnd]

let part: String = template[firstSubstring.endIndex...secondSubstring.startIndex]
```

After all I have a template string and two substrings of it. I want to get a `String` ranging from the end of the first `Substring` to the start of the second `Substring`.

Comment: What type is your property `template`? Seems that it is declared as `String`. The main issue is the use of a `ClosedRange` instead of `Range` and type mismatch trying to assign a `Substring` to a `String` or a combination of both. try `let part: String = template[template.startIndex...template.endIndex]` would throw `Subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires the types 'String.Index' and 'Int' be equivalent`

Comment: @MartinR I updated the playground code to reproduce my problem in the first snippet.

Comment: @LeoDabus `template` indeed is a `String`. I forgot to mention that. Indeed it was an actually obvious type mismatch. Oops. Xcode really distracted me from that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The current version of Swift works with the [`Substring`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/substring) struct which is a sliced `String`.

The error seems to be misleading and occurs if you are going to assign a (range-subscripted) `Substring` to a `String` variable.

To fix the error create a `String` from the `Substring`

```
iteration.template = String(template[iterationSubstring.endIndex...substring.startIndex])
```

Nevertheless you are strongly discouraged from creating ranges with indices from different strings (`iterationSubstring` and `substring`). Slice the main string, the indices are preserved.

---

The crash in the second (meanwhile deleted) example occurred because the last character of a string is *at index before `endIndex`*, it's

```
template[template.startIndex..<template.endIndex]
```

or shorter

```
template[template.startIndex...]
```

Comment: Indeed it was misleading! I attempted to assign a `Substring` to a `String`. Wrapping it into `String()` solves the issue. I still need to get used to this. I will elaborate on my original question, too, as @MartinR suggested.

Comment: After your edit: `part` is `Substring` even if you annotate `String` which causes the mentioned error. Remove the annotation and create a string with `String(...)`. To get the substring you can also write `template[firstSubstringEnd..<secondSubstringStart]`

Comment: In the real project code the equivalent of `part` is a `String` property on an object to keep things separated. I added the type annotation in the playground code for explanation. It is necessary to produce the misleading error.

Comment: By the way you can write shorter: `let firstSubstringEnd = template.index(template.startIndex, offsetBy: 8); let secondSubstringStart = template.index(template.startIndex, offsetBy: 10);  let part = template[firstSubstringEnd...secondSubstringStart]`

Comment: This is bug [SR-11702](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11702), and has been fixed on master.