# Swift 5.1 Substring Issue

Tags: substring, swift5

I am a newbie in Swift. I use Swift 5.1
I want to get a substring from a string but I was not able to.
I already tried several solutions([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677330/how-does-string-substring-work-in-swift), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191934/swift-easy-way-to-substring)) but those didn't work for me.

I tried it like this :

[image: Screenshot]

```
func substring(x : Int, y : Int, s : String) -> String {
  let start = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: x);
  let end   = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: y);
  return s[start..<end];
}

print(substring(x: 0, y: 2, s: "abcde"))
```

> /tmp/306AE87E-57C7-417C-B2EF-313A921E75B9.BuUdsc/main.swift:6:11:
>   error: subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires the types 'String.Index' and
>   'Int' be equivalent   return s[start..(bounds: R) -> String where R : RangeExpression, R.Bound == Int { get }
>              ^

I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: The wrong error message is a bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11702

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is again one of those confusing error messages that doesn't tell you want you actually did wrong.

You should do this:

```
return String(s[start..<end])
```

This is because the subscript that takes a `Range<String.Index>` actually returns a `Substring`, but your method returns a `String`, so you have to convert it before returning.

Speculation on why the error message is outputted:

Seeing that the method returns a `String`, the Swift compiler tries to find a  subscript which returns a `String`, and some how it found one (I couldn't), but that overload only works on types with the `Index` associated type being `Int`.

Comment: The wrong error message is a bug, compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60095464/why-does-string-subscript-require-the-types-string-index-and-int-to-be-e#comment106288936_60095872.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is mostly fine but Swift is messing up the error message. I tried your code in the Xcode 11.4 beta with Swift 5.2 better error diagnostics and it complained that the return type `String` is incorrect because `s[start..<end]` gives you a `Substring`. You can either change the return type:

```
func substring(x : Int, y : Int, s : String) -> Substring {
  let start = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: x)
  let end   = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: y)
  return s[start..<end]
}

print(substring(x: 0, y: 2, s: "abcde"))
```

or convert the substring to a string:

```
func substring(x : Int, y : Int, s : String) -> String {
  let start = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: x)
  let end   = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: y)
  return String(s[start..<end])
}

print(substring(x: 0, y: 2, s: "abcde"))
```

Sidenote: the `;` is not required in Swift and it's a convention to not use it unless you want to have multiple statements on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

As your function returns a String, you need to convert `s[start..<end]` which is `Substring` to `String`.

```
func substring(x : Int, y : Int, s : String) -> String {
  let start = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: x);
  let end   = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: y);
    return String(s[start..<end])
}

print(substring(x: 0, y: 2, s: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
```

Output:

```
ab
```